# Change Arrow Direction Column Img: ASC/DESC ==>php/sql

Tags: javascript, php, sql

On each column click, the column will do an ASC or DESC. On a ASC, I want to change the column image from down to up:
https://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/

In Jquery, I would assume to use SQL "Get" statement? (because it could be currently ASC or DESC).

I am not worried about SQL Injections/PDO as I am adding that code later.

```
$(".column_sort").on('click', function () {
  alert("Table will now sort.")
}); 

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
} 

$sort = ($sort == 'DESC') ? 'ASC': 'DESC';
$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY $order $sort";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query); ?>

<th>
    <a class="column_sort" id="id" href="?order=id&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
        ID<span id="arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

Comment: why don't you consider using [JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) for this? But if you still want to use your method then you should use prepared statement to prevent sql injection

Comment: https://datatables.net/blog/2017-01-19   Yeah. I am planning on making this using Ajax/Jquery using that link which appears to be the same as yours actually... but I wanted to "finish" this one first without it. I suppose I will just jump ship on this project to the datatable.net way.

Comment: Miggy, I am making my Database.net table. By your comment, I am assuming that means that database.net is much secure with SQL injections?

Comment: Hi sir. I think its secure from sql injection. It already has a funcitionality of sorting columns without making another request.